# Reformat an object to make it more shallow

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In the example object myObject, every object get's stored using a numbered key.

```
> 0: {Foo: {...}}
> 1: {Bar: {...}}
```

To access a value in that object, the integer needs to be added:

`console.log(myObject[0].Foo)`

How to re-format an object so that you get an object with a key value pair as follows:

`console.log(myObject.Foo)`

I've tried so far:

```js
const myObject = [
 {
   "Foo": {
     "test": "output of foo"
    }
  },
  {
   "Bar": {
     "test": "output of bar"
    }
  }
]

console.log(myObject[0].Foo.test);
// desired result:
// console.log(myObject.Foo.test);
// should output: output of foo

function extend(obj, src) {
    Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
    return obj;
}

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function (r) {
 const newKey = Object.keys(myObject[r])[0];
 const newValue = myObject[r][newKey];
  // console.log('key: ', newKey); // output: Foo
  // console.log('value: ', newValue); // output: {"test": "output of bar"}
  extend([newKey], {newValue});
}, []);
```

Comment: If you don't want it to be an array why not make it an object with a bunch of nested objects?

Comment: How is `myObject` constructed, where are you getting it from? Maybe you should simply fix the code that creates it.

Comment: the code comes for differen instances from different sources. I'm looking for a way to format the data in a way the function requires it before I use it with that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myObject` is an array, so you shouldn't use `Object.keys` with that. Just do

```
function extend(obj, src) {
    Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
    return obj;
}

var result = myObject.reduce(extend, {});
```

Or with ES6:

```
var results = Object.assign({}, ...myObject);
```

Comment: Nice second solution +1

Comment: Is this really what the OP wants? I sounds like they want a single lever object with `key: stringValue`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think so: "*desired result:
`console.log(myObject.Foo.test);` should output: `output of foo`*". One could drop the `test` as well to make it even flatter.

Comment: @Bergi, I must have misunderstood (clearly since this has been marked correct). I thought `myObject.Foo` should equal `output of foo`

Comment: Mainly I was looking for a way to lose the integer from the object to make it 'flat'. This solves the purpose.

Comment: However, I found the answer you proposed also very interesting @MarkMeyer. It might be that if there is a different data structure, I might need that one as well. Do you mind sharing that code again? (perhaps as an answer or fiddle in a comment)

Comment: @Remi I undeleted the answer in case it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce function !

```
    const myObject = [
    {
    "Foo": {
        "test": "output of foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "Bar": {
        "test": "output of bar"
    }
  }
]

console.log(myObject[0].Foo.test);
myObject.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return {...acc, ...curr};
}, {})
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single key with a single string value you need to make a few assumptions about the data structure. For example keys can't split into objects with more keys because in this case it's not clear which value the parent key should get. You can traverse the object until you find the base value with a simple recursive function. Then call it in a reduce loop with your top level keys:

```js
const myObject = [{"Foo": {"test": "output of foo"}},{"Bar": {"test": "output of bar"}}]

// Get the leaf node value:
const getLastVal = (obj) => (typeof obj !== 'object' || typeof obj === null) ?  obj : getLastVal(Object.values(obj)[0]);
  
let obj = myObject.reduce((obj, cur) => {
    Object.entries(cur).forEach(( [k, v]) =>  obj[k] = getLastVal(v))
    return obj
}, {})
console.log(obj)
```